# std::ostream Composition of Classes

Tags: c++, class, oop, std, ostream

We have the following situation:

In Classes A and B, we have overridden the `<<` operator.
Now, we have a new class C with data members of objects of A and B.
How would we override the `<<` operator here?

To be more specific,
We need something like this:
`cout<<objectOfC`  corresponds to `cout<<correspondingObjectOfA<<correspondingObjectOfB`

I'm not getting how to modify the ostream& object so as to return it back.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const C& obj){   // This is a friend function declared in C.h
    A* a = obj.AObject; // Returns the corresponding object of A
    B* b = obj.BObject; // Returns the corresponding object of B
    
    // Need to modify out somehow to 'cout' A and B respectively when cout is called on an object of C

    return out;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you already have appropriate overrides for `A` and `B`, just use them.

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const C& obj) {
    out << *obj.AObject << *obj.BObject;
    return out;
}
```

Because `operator<<` returns its `ostream` argument, you can further condense this:

```
ostream& operator<< (ostream& out, const C& obj) {
    return out << *obj.AObject << *obj.BObject;
}
```

Comment: Don't need the separate output and return statements, as the `operator<<` function returns the stream. Just do `return out << ...;`

Comment: @bruno Yes, I will. There is a timer for that, apparently. I can only accept answers after it expires. Just wanted to convey my gratitude till then :)

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude I've included that as an alternate implementation. When I was checking to see how it's usually written, I saw the statements separated (e.g. [Microsoft's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/standard-library/overloading-the-output-operator-for-your-own-classes?view=msvc-160)). I'm sure the compiler optimizes it down to the same code, so it comes down to which one you think is more readable.